# Problem with matrices in Python

Tags: python

I was writing a programm in Python (2.5.4), and I realized that my code was not working because of something very unusual. I am going to give an example:

```
A = [[0]*2]*2
```

When I print A, I get:

```
[[0, 0], [0, 0]]
```

That is ok. But now I want to change the element in the first column and firts row. So I type:

```
A[0][0] = 1
```

But when I print A again, I get:

```
[[1, 0], [1, 0]]
```

However, I was expecting

```
[[1, 0], [0, 0]]
```

This is ruinning all my code. I want to know why this is happening and how I can fix it.

On the other hand, when I type:

```
B = [[0,0],[0,0]]
```

And make:

```
B[0][0] = 1
```

I get:

```
[[1, 0], [0, 0]]
```

This is even stranger! Aren't the two ways of implementing matrices equivalent? What if I wanted a 100x100 matrix with zeros? For this case, with a 2x2 matrix, I can type [[0, 0], [0, 0]]. But that is not a good solution.

Comment: More generally, use numpy (http://www.numpy.org/) to do numerical computing instead of rolling your own.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because your list contains several ***references*** to a list.

```
>>> a = [0]
>>> l = [a,a]
>>> l[0][0] = "A"
>>> l
[['A'], ['A']]
```

We create a list and binded it to `a`. We then store two **references** to `a` in the list `l` via `l=[a,a]`. Then we manipulate **one** reference to `a`, and change it's first element to `"A"`. Since a reference *refers* to a location in memory, my manipulating that reference (either element in `l`) we change the value in memory, hence affecting all other references to `a`.

[image]

This illustration, depicts the example above. The arrows represent a reference to `a`. They **are** the `a`'s in `l = [a,a]`. When you change one of them, you change the value which they **both** point to. That interaction could be depicted like this:

[image]

We manipulate `a` via manipulating `l[0]` (`l[0]` is a reference to `a`), as such we can change the first element in `a` by changing `l[0][0]` (which would be the same as `a[0]`) to `"A"`.

A depiction your list `[[0]*2]*2` would look like this

[image]

Answer (score 4):

"What if you wanted a 100 x 100 matrix of zeros?"

Use a list comprehension:

```
[[0] * 100 for x in range(100)]
```